# Incorrectly Binding Data in MVVM Utilizing Prism and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism

I'm picking back up on an application I started awhile back.
I'm creating an application utilizing Xamarin and Prism for MVVM, and utilizing an ASP.NET WEB API.

I have an API working correctly, but I think I'm missing something in terms of "wiring" the View Model.

Here is an example of my ViewModel:

```
        private string _technician;

    public string Technician
    {
        get { return _technician; }
        set { _technician = value; }
    }
```

And using RestSharp to POST:

```
            var client = new RestClient("http:apiurl/");
        var request = new RestRequest("api", Method.POST);
        WorkOrderLog orderLog = new WorkOrderLog();

        orderLog.Technician = Technician;
        orderLog.WOType = "M";
        orderLog.AssetDesc = AssetDesc;
        orderLog.AssetNumber = AssetNumber;
        orderLog.DeptCode = DeptCode;
        orderLog.FaultCode = FaultCode;
        orderLog.Priority = Priority;
        orderLog.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        orderLog.Active = true;
        orderLog.Complete = false;
        orderLog.Suspended = false;

        request.AddJsonBody(orderLog);
        client.Execute(request);
```

When I run the action to POST, I insert data succesfully into the table, but am getting NULL values for the values I am trying to bind on the View. So the Static WOType works, but the others don't for example.

Here is the Binding to the View:

```
<Picker Title="Priority" SelectedItem="{Binding Priority, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
<Label Text="Technician"  FontSize="Large" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" BindingContext="{Binding Technician}"></Label>
```

Am I overlooking something simple? I'm utilizing the AutoWireViewModel inside of Prism.
Again, utilizing Prism MVVM with Xamarin.

Thank you guys for assisting.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are missing a few things.

Since you are using Prism your ViewModel should look like this

```
public class YourViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public Untitled-4(Parameters)
    {

    }

    private string _technician;
    public string Technician
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _technician, value);
    }

   ...
   //The rest of your properties should look like the one above
}
```

On the XAML the binding should be:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Technician}"  FontSize="Large" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

You don't need to set the Context Xamarin.Forms and Prism will take care of that since you are using `AutoWireViewModel`.

Something I am not understanding is why Binding to a Label. Maybe what you want is to use an Entry where you can get information from the user.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Technician, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Note: For more information about Prims and XF: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/creating-your-first-prism-app.html